# Member "mint" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract ERC20

Tags: solidity

I am trying to mint ERC20 tokens from another contract. I will add this contract address to the 'minter' role on the ERC20 contract.

I've noted below where I get the error.
It's unclear to me why totalSupply() works but _mint(...) does not.

Also I am interested in why some functions on Open Zepplin contracts begin with an underscore.

Thank you !

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract claimTest {

    ERC20 public token;
    ERC20 public token2;
    address private tokenAddress;
    uint private fixedAmount;

    constructor () {
    }

    function setToken(ERC20 _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    function setAddress(address _address) public {
        tokenAddress = _address;
        token2 = ERC20(_address);
     }

    // Error
    // Member "mint" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract ERC20
    function claim() public {
        token._mint(msg.sender, fixedAmount);
    }

    // This works
    function totalSupply()  public view returns (uint) {
        return token.totalSupply();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_mint is an internal function, you need to [inherit](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=Inheritance%20#inheritance) ERC20. If you want to create your own ERC20 token, you can do something like that. Note you need to inherit ERC20 like  `MyToken is ERC20`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;
        
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

error MyToken__MintNotAuthorized(address caller);

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        // Mint 100 tokens to msg.sender
        // 1 token = 1 * (10 ** decimals)
        _mint(msg.sender, 100 * 10**uint(decimals()));
    }

    // mint can be called by authorised caller to mint MyToken in existence.  
    function mint(address beneficiary, uint256 mintAmount) external {
        // Checks: the caller is the Authorised  caller
        if (msg.sender != "0xabc...") {
            revert MyToken__MintNotAuthorized(msg.sender);
        }
        
        // Effects: print the new MyTokens into existence.
        _mint(beneficiary, mintAmount);
            
    }
}
```

Check out [this](http://import%20%22@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol%22;) or [this](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/understand-the-erc-20-token-smart-contract/) example to see how to create an ERC20 and how to call it.